# Tensorflow.js returns "NaN" Value when running Linear Regression Model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, linear-regression, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to run this linear regression model which would essentially give me an output based on `const prediction = model.predict((tf.tensor2d([20], [1,1])));` I'm however unfortunately getting NaN Value everytime I run the code to receive a prediction.

What's the best way to approach a solution? Are there other methods?

Thank you!

Below is the code:

```js
async function learnLinear() {
  const fontSize = document.getElementById("count").innerHTML;
  const parsed = parseInt(fontSize);

  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1] }));

  const learningRate = 0.0001;
  const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);

  model.compile({
loss: "meanSquaredError",
optimizer: "sgd",
  });

  const xs = tf.tensor2d(
[
  54,
  20,
  22,
  34,
  18,
  47,
  28,
  54,
  36,
  51,
  44,
  31,
  39,
  19,
  45,
  48,
  32,
  27,
  25,
  54,
  27,
  38,
  25,
  38,
  57,
  49,
  28,
  19,
  59,
  28,
  27,
  55,
  60,
  49,
  40,
  45,
  35,
  45,
  39,
  25,
  50,
  58,
  28,
  59,
  21,
  37,
  47,
  31,
  46,
  18,
],
[50, 1]
  );
  const ys = tf.tensor2d(
[
  14,
  15,
  15,
  15,
  16,
  17,
  15,
  16,
  15,
  17,
  17,
  15,
  16,
  15,
  15,
  16,
  17,
  17,
  17,
  14,
  16,
  15,
  15,
  16,
  17,
  15,
  16,
  14,
  15,
  16,
  14,
  17,
  15,
  14,
  14,
  17,
  15,
  14,
  14,
  16,
  16,
  14,
  14,
  17,
  17,
  14,
  17,
  14,
  14,
  17,
],
[50, 1]
  );

  await model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 500 });

  const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([20], [1, 1]));
  const value = prediction.dataSync()[0];

  console.log("Prediction", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify what metric the model is supposed to track.

```
const batchSize = 32;
const epochs = 500;

model.compile({
  loss: "meanSquaredError",
  optimizer: "sgd",
  metrics: ["mse"],
});

await model.fit(xs, ys, batchSize, epochs);

const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([20], [1, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that might run into this error in the future.

What works for me is changing the loss function from `"meanSquaredError"` such as (`loss: "meanSquaredError"` to `loss: "meanAbsoluteError"`):

```
...
model.compile({
  loss: "meanAbsoluteError",
  optimizer: "sgd",
});
...
```

**What does meanAbsoluteError loss function does?**

Calculate how far is our model predictions output is from the targets (that is taking their difference), then take the absolute of the difference so as to make it positive and finally, it return the average of the differences.

Mathematically:

```
meanAbsoluteError = average(absolute(modelOutput - target))

modelOutput = [2.0, 3.4, 3.3]
target = [2.1, 3.2, 3.4]

meanAbsoluteError = average(|2.0 - 2.1| + |3.4 - 3.2| + |3.3 - 3.4|)

meanAbsoluteError = 0.13
```